# Nested php code cause error from the php code inside

Tags: php

I have php code like this

```
<?php 
            if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
                get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );

            endwhile;

            <?php next_posts_link( 'Previous' ); ?>

        endif;

?>
```

However, I get this error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<', expecting elseif (T_ELSEIF) or else (T_ELSE) or endif (T_ENDIF) in .../index.php on line 14

Line 14 is: `<?php next_posts_link( 'Previous' ); ?>` , remove this line it works normally

I use Atom for PHP coding and I see the `endif; ?>` get grayed out

Comment: Why `<?php` you are already in PHP.

Comment: You're already in PHP, so why do you have a nested `<?php`?

Comment: the php for Previous is for making the Previous post for wordpress

Comment: You are already in a PHP block though so you just need `next_posts_link( 'Previous' );`.

Comment: Right, before continuing, you need to start with some PHP tutorials.

Comment: Well the comment from chris85 does help

Answer (score 0):

Well, for anyone or newbies want to know the answer. I just need

```
next_posts_link( 'Previous' );
```

instead of

```
<?php next_posts_link( 'Previous' ); ?>
```

Comment: yes, thanks for your help